# jquery slider .on()

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following jquery code:

```
    $('div#headBannerSearchAgedBetweenSlider').slider({
            range: true,
            min: 18,
            max: 99,
            values: [18, 65],
            change: function(event, ui) {
                    $('span#headerBannerAgedMin').html(ui.values[0]);
                    $('span#headerBannerAgedMax').html(ui.values[1]);
            },
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                if (ui.values[0] == ui.values[1]) {return false;}
            }
    });
```

The catch is the element 'div#headBannerSearchAgedBetweenSlider' is not avalible when the js script is loaded so I need to use something like .live() or .on() to attach the slide event once the element is avaliable.

How do I bind slide to the element 'div#headBannerSearchAgedBetweenSlider' once its visible? I tried to wrap the code in the following (using $(this) as the element but I'm not using a click event. I just needs to bind once the element exists.

```
     $(document).on('click','div#headBannerSearchAgedBetweenSlider', function() {
     });
```

How do I do this?

thankyou

---

I have tried the following .ready() without luck - is there anything obviously wrong with this?

```
$('div#headBannerSearchAgedBetweenSlider').ready(function() {
    $('div#headBannerSearchAgedBetweenSlider').slider({
            range: true,
            min: 18,
            max: 99,
            values: [18, 65],
            change: function(event, ui) {
                    $('span#headerBannerAgedMin').html(ui.values[0]);
                    $('span#headerBannerAgedMax').html(ui.values[1]);
            },
            slide: function(event, ui) {
                if (ui.values[0] == ui.values[1]) {return false;}
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: What triggers the creation of your `$('div#headBannerSearchAgedBetweenSlider')`?

Comment: That DIV is loaded when I user access a page using jquery .load. I think I'm getting where you going... I would need to attached the event handler when the DIV is .load().

Comment: Exactly, just be aware that `load` is async (so you cannot just put the plugin-call in the next line), and you have to call the `.slider()` in some sort of callback. See: http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function on info how to do that.

Comment: `ready` was a bad idea for this.sorry.ready actually fires when the whole dom is ready..thts it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the plugin once your `#headBannerSearchAgedBetweenSlider` element has been loaded / is present in the DOM. Since you seem to be using **[`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/)** (async) to load your content dynamically it should work like this (I am assuming that you load the `div` in question into an element `#wrapper` here):

```
$('#wrapper').load('/what/ever.php', function(){ //this function will be executed once your content is successfully loaded
    $('div#headBannerSearchAgedBetweenSlider').slider({/*..options go here..*/});
});
```

See the **[docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/#callback-function)** for info on callback-functions for AJAX calls.